# Bootstrap image popup

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popup

I am using bootstrap and have a button:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Popup image</button>
```

I have an image on the same directory and would like to have it popup in some kind of overlay where the background is grey if that is possible. I am used to javascript, so normally would do something like onclick and call a function that would do it. But in bootstrap I am unsure of how to do this. Thank you

Comment: Is this helpful for you: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can do something like this..

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Popup image</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <img src="//placehold.it/1000x600" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/123443

Comment: How do you get the modal in the center of your screen?

Comment: It should be centered. The demo is not centered for you?

Comment: Yes, horizontal, but not vertical

Comment: Great answer @Skelly, and followup in comments as well.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25023199/bootstrap-open-image-in-modal) is another example which helped me to `create light box effect`